# How can I find in C++ which child class is calling the function of the parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, fopen

I have a class `A` which has a function called `openFile(const char * name)`, which opens a file.

I have two child classes `Reader` and `Writer`

`Reader` opens the file in a reading mode.
`Writer` opens the file in a writing mode.

I'm using `fopen` to open the file.

I would like to open this file in either a reading mode or a writing mode, depending on which child class is calling this method.

Is it possible to do this without sending any extra parameters to the parent class?

Comment: Your question is quite obvious and I think that you didn't look for your answer in Internet on your own, just wrote your question here. Look for "Polymorphism" in google or bing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, something like this is exactly what inheritance is meant to do:

```
class A {
    public:
    virtual void openFile(const char* name) = 0; 
    // If A cannot open a file on its own, else implement it

    // rest of implementation
};

class Reader : public A {
    public:
    virtual void openFile(const char* name) {//open file in read mode}
    //rest of implemenation
};
```

and handle `Write` analog. Then, given a pointer or reference of type `A*` or `A&` pointing or referring to one of the children, the right function will be chosen:

```
A* a1 = new Reader{};
A* a2 = new Writer{};

a1->openFile("test.in");  // calls Reader.openFile()
a2->openFile("test.out"); // calls Writer.openFile()
```